# match element in array of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-scala-driver

I have collection as follows .

```
{
 "name" : "pqr" ,
 "loc" : 
   [ 
    {"area" : "c" , "country" : "d"},
    {"area" : "w" , "country" : "r"}
   ]
}
```

I want to make which match such that only match the first element of array loc

that means if

1. gives area as c or country d then it return document.
2. gives area as w or country as r then does not return element

only match first element of mongo array

Is this possible in mongo ?

if some one knows plz reply

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you want return only first matched element you should use `limit(n)` and queries like this:

*1.gives area as c or country d then it return document.*

```
db.items.find( { $or : [ {"loc.area": "c" } , 
                         {"loc.country ": "d" } ] } ).limit(1);
```

*2.gives area as w or country as r then does not return element*

```
db.items.find( { $or : [ {"loc.area":  { "$ne" : "w" } }, 
                         {"loc.country": { "$ne" : "r" } } ] } ).limit(1);
```

If you want to search only in the first elements of nested array you can do it using positional operator by adding `.0.` -> `loc.0.area`.

**Update:** I've misunderstand your question first. Now i see that you looking for **loc.0.area**.